# Animate camera alternating constrained paths

Tags: animation, camera, path

all, I am new to blender, so sorry if my question seems dumb.

I just animated a camera to follow a bezier path. Now, I need to keep animating the camera, but I would like to either free the camera from the path or to follow a different path.

So, this is my question: **is it possible to animate camera alternating among different bezier paths?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple paths.

The influence value in the follow path modifier can be animated. A value of 0 means that the modifier will have no influence on the object's trajectory.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @susu! I tried to animate the influence. But the camera gets crazy, rotating and changin place when i vanish the influence. And it also messes up the animation at frames before I vanish it. So, I would like to keep animating leaving from the last view from the animated path to a new location...